# merge multiple rows based on a key column

Tags: text-processing, awk

My csv file looks like the following:

```
8 id1 xyz
1 id1 abcdef
2 id1 mv
1 id1 tzfl
6 id2 xyz
1 id2 abcdef
1 id2 mv
5 id3 xyz
2 id3 abcdef
   ...
8 id100 xyz
1 id100 abcdef
2 id100 mv
1 id100 tzfl
4 id100 glkgb
```

I want to sort this file according to the same ID, and then print column3 and column1 in the following format.

```
       xyz abcdef mv tzfl glkgb
id1    8   1      2  1
id2    6   1      1
id3    5   2
   ...
id100  8   1      2  1    4
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to do the cross-tabulation straightforwardly using GNU Datamash (`datamash -Ws --filler= crosstab 2,3 unique 1 < file`) however AFAIK it doesn't allow control of the output order

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is a good tool for this. There is a great tutorial about `awk`: [Awk - A Tutorial and Introduction - by Bruce Barnett - Grymoire](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Give a try to this:

```
awk '
{
  columns[$3]=1 ; ids[$2]=1 ; col1[$2 ":::" $3]=$1
  if (maxcollen< length($1)) maxcollen=length($1)
  if (maxcollen< length($2)) maxcollen=length($2) 
  if (maxcollen< length($3)) maxcollen=length($3) 
}
END {
  printf("%-" maxcollen "s ", "")
  for (key in columns) {
    printf("%-" maxcollen "s ",key)
  }
  for (id in ids) {
    printf("\n%-" maxcollen "s ", id)
    for (key in columns) {
      printf("%-" maxcollen "s ", col1[id ":::" key])
    }
  }
  printf("\n")      
}' myfile.csv
```

Output:

```
              glkgb  tzfl   mv     abcdef xyz    
id3                                2      5      
id100         4      1      2      1      8      
id1                  1      2      1      8      
id2                         1      1      6
```

## ==

Another version to display the columns and ids in order of appearance:

```
awk '
{
  if (colname[$3]!=1) {colname[$3]=1 ; cols[++coln]=$3 }
  if (idval[$2]!=1) {idval[$2]=1 ; ids[++idn]=$2 }
  col1[$2 ":::" $3]=$1
  if (maxcollen< length($1)) maxcollen=length($1)
  if (maxcollen< length($2)) maxcollen=length($2) 
  if (maxcollen< length($3)) maxcollen=length($3) 
}
END {
  printf("%-" maxcollen "s ", "")
  for (i=1; i<=coln ; i++ ) {
    printf("%-" maxcollen "s ",cols[i])
  }
  for (j=1; j<=idn ; j++) {
    printf("\n%-" maxcollen "s ", ids[j])
    for (i=1; i<=coln ; i++) {
      printf("%-" maxcollen "s ", col1[ids[j] ":::" cols[i]])
    }
  }
  printf("\n")      
}' myfile.csv
```

Output:

```
       xyz    abcdef mv     tzfl   glkgb  
id1    8      1      2      1             
id2    6      1      1                    
id3    5      2                           
id100  8      1      2      1      4
```